# How do you find and modify existing menu commands in Visual Studio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vsix

I'm currently writing a plugin/extension for Visual Studio and I'd like to be able to find an existing menu command and hide it. Specifically, I want to find the Rebuild commands in the context menus and hide or disable them. It looks like I have access to the command IDs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vsconstants.vsstd2kcmdid(v=vs.140).aspx

And using OleMenuCommandService there is a FindCommand but it returns NULL. Here is what I'm currently trying:

```
OleMenuCommandService mcs = GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
if ( null != mcs )
{
    MenuCommand rebuildCommand = mcs.FindCommand(new CommandID(
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.UICONTEXT_SolutionHasSingleProject,
        (int)Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.RebuildCtx) );

    // rebuildCommand is NULL
}
```

Any ideas on the way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears to be impossible to get an existing Visual Studio command using FindCommand method.  You can see more detailed information on the [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/015b1f0c-ae15-413e-bd52-774fd73a45f9/sdk-package-olemenucommandservicefindcommand-always-returns-null?forum=vsx).

Also, I think it's not a good idea to make some existing Visual Studio features unavailable in an extension. Instead, you can subscribe to the `CommandEvents.BeforeExecute` and `CommandEvents.AfterExecute` events. Here's how to do it:

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;

...

DTE2 ide = ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2);
CommandEvents commandEvents = ide.Events.CommandEvents;
commandEvents.BeforeExecute += OnBeforeExecute;
commandEvents.AfterExecute += OnAfterExecute;

...

private void OnBeforeExecute(string Guid, int ID, object CustomIn, object CustomOut, ref bool CancelDefault)
{
    if (ID == (int)VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.RebuildCtx)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

private void OnAfterExecute(string Guid, int ID, object CustomIn, object CustomOut, ref bool CancelDefault)
{
    if (ID == (int)VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.RebuildCtx)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! I think I can make this work even though I agree it's not ideal -- perhaps another approach would be to override the global Visual Studio settings to hide certain commands like you can do with Tools > Customize? Maybe the "right" question is how to change settings programmatically?

Comment: I think it should be
`void OnAfterExecute(string Guid, int ID, object CustomIn, object CustomOut)`,
without the last argument.